# Questions about expectation of stochastic integrals

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, expectation

I am considering the following SDEs:

$$dX_1=-\theta(X_1-a_1)dt+\sqrt{X_1}(1-X_1)dW_1-X_1\sqrt{X_2}dW_2$$
$$dX_2=-\theta(X_2-a_2)dt-X_2\sqrt{X_1}dW_1+\sqrt{X_2}(1-X_2)dW_2$$

Here $W_1$ and $W_2$are both Brownian motions and they are independent.

Is there anyway that I can calculate the following expectation?
$$E\left(\int_s^t\sqrt{1-X_1}dW_1 \cdot \int_s^t\sqrt{\frac{X_1X_2}{1-X_1}}dW_2\right)$$

I know if the integrand is adapted to the filtration, we can use Ito isometry, but here I am not sure if I can still use that.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Also, how can I calculate $E(\int_s^t X_1 dW_1)$, I know if the integrand is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$ then the expectation is zero, but here $X_1$ depends on both $W_1$ and $W_2$, seems it is not adapted to the filtration of only $W_1$ or $W_2$..

Comment: Are $dW_1(s)$ and $dW_2(t)$ independent of each other?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I fergot to mention that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are Brownian motions and they are independent.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that $X_1$ and $X_2$ stay in $(0,1)$? Otherwise, the random variables in the expectation do not even *exist*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expectation is zero, if $dW_1(s)$ and $dW_2(t)$ are independent of each other $\forall s, t$. Let $\omega$ stand for an event. We have

$$E\Big[\int_s^t f(\omega,x)dW_1(x) \int_s^t g(\omega,y)dW_2(y)\Big] = E\Big[\lim\limits_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\sum_{x,y} f(\omega,x)g(\omega,x) E\Big[\big(W_1(x+\delta x)-W_1(x)\big)\big(W_2(x+\delta x)-W_2(x)\big)\big|\mathcal F_x \Big] \Big]
= 0,$$
by Riemann sum (definition of Ito integral) and the law of iterated expectation and the fact that.
$$E\Big[f(\omega,x)\big(W_1(x+\delta x)-W_1(x)\big)g(\omega,x)\big(W_2(x+\delta x)-W_2(x)\big)\big|\mathcal F_x \Big] 
= f(\omega,x)g(\omega,x)E\Big[\big(W_1(x+\delta x)-W_1(x)\big)\big(W_2(x+\delta x)-W_2(x)\big)\big|\mathcal F_x \Big] =f(\omega,x)g(\omega,x)E\Big[\big(W_1(x+\delta x)-W_1(x)\big)\big|\mathcal F_x\Big]E\Big[\big(W_2(x+\delta x)-W_2(x)\big)\big|\mathcal F_x\Big] = 0,$$
due to the martingale property of the Brownian motion.

Comment: Could you please tell me more details about how you get this result? This is the result I expact but I am not sure how to get it. Or any references?

Comment: Thank you. May be stupid question, but here $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are also processes depending on $W_1$ and $W_2$, we can also extend the expectation like this? Don't we need to take expectation on $f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: @DEW: This is a good question. Does the last added line answer your question?

Comment: So here you suppose the filtration is $\sigma(W_1,W_2)$,right?

Comment: @DEW: You are correct. Also, what I have written is a sketch. If you write it up, you need to add in the details to make it really rigorous, such as passing the Riemann sum to Ito integral.

Comment: $$E\Big[f(x)\big(W_1(x+\delta x)-W_1(x)\big)g(x)\big(W_2(x+\delta x)-W_2(x)\big)\big|\mathcal F_x \Big] = E\Big[f(x)\big(W_1(x+\delta x)-W_1(x)\big)\big|\mathcal F_x\Big]E\Big[g(x)\big(W_2(x+\delta x)-W_2(x)\big)\big|\mathcal F_x\Big] = 0.$$ Here $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not independent, why we can write like this?

Comment: @DEW: A better presentation is in the answer. $f$ and $g$ are technically independent, actually deterministic not random conditioned on filtration $\mathcal F_x$ at time $x$. So they can be taken out of the conditional expectation operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @DEW: You are welcome. Are you able to up-vote the answer?

Comment: I tried but I dont have enough reputation for now. I will keep this in mind and vote your answer when I am able to. Thanks for your timw again.